# how to get name of the instance? ruby

Tags: ruby

I know that `self.class.name` returns name of the class but how about instance?

For example this code

```
module Selling
  def sell
    puts "#{self.class.name} has been sold"
  end
end

class Shop
  include Selling
  def initialize(id)
    @id=id
  end
end

book=Shop.new(1132)
book.sell
```

prints `Shop` and what I need is a `book`

Comment: I don't understand your example code. Is `Shop` a shop or a book? And is `1132` a shop id or a book id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects don't have names. They may or may not be referenced by one or more variables, but there is no way to know what variables reference an object and what the names of those variables are.

Modules are a special case, their `name` method indeed returns the name of the first constant that they have been assigned to, but that is interpreter magic.

Answer (score 0):

Jörg W Mittag [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635568/477037) that you can't inspect variable names.

Here's an attempt to solve your problem by using a separate `Book` instance with a `name` attribute:

```
module Selling
  def sell(item)
    puts "#{item.name} has been sold"
  end
end

class Shop
  include Selling
end

class Book
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

bookstore = Shop.new

book1 = Book.new('Moby-Dick')
book2 = Book.new('Of Mice and Men')

bookstore.sell(book1)
bookstore.sell(book2)
```

Output:

```
Moby-Dick has been sold
Of Mice and Men has been sold
```